# Is there any way to sumif with an if condition in the criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to create a `SUMIF()` formula in excel that has a `if` condition built in

It should run through the A column and look for kosher then go to B column and check for Albany, but it should also count the "non-albany."

However, if I check for San Fran, it should run through both but the result should exclude row 4 bc it belongs to the Albany group

```
Expected Results:
Albany = 3
San Fran = 1
Ok = 1
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Do you mean COUNTIFS or SUMIFS? What's the function of column C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=LET(data,A1:B5,
     a,INDEX(data,,1),
     b,INDEX(data,,2),
     c,IF(a="non-albany","albany",b),
     u,UNIQUE(b),
CHOOSE({1,2},
       u, 
       BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,
             LET(y,FILTER(c,c=x,0),
             SUM(IF(y=0,0,1)))))))
```

[image]

Or if you want to sum the values of column C conditionally, you could use:

```
=LET(data,A1:C5,
     a,INDEX(data,,1),
     b,INDEX(data,,2),
     c,INDEX(data,,3),
     d,IF(a="non-albany","albany",b),
     u,UNIQUE(b),
CHOOSE({1,2},
       u, 
       BYROW(u,LAMBDA(x,             
             LET(y,FILTER(c,d=x,0),
             SUM(y))))))
```

[image]

This could also be accomplished with MMULT for older versions:

```
=MMULT(N(D12:D15=TRANSPOSE(IF(A1:A5="non-albany","albany",B1:B5)))*TRANSPOSE(C1:C5),ROW(C1:C5)^0)
```

Where `D12:D15` hold the unique values from column B.

Answer (score 2):

Requirement :

1] It should run through the A column and look for **kosher** then go to B column and check for **Albany**, but it should also count the "**non-albany**"

2] However, if I check for San Fran, it should run through both but the result should exclude row 4 bc it belongs to the Albany group

Formula in F1, copied down :

=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("kosher",$A$1:$A$5))*($B$1:$B$5=E1),$C$1:$C$5)+SUMPRODUCT((LOWER($A$1:$A$5)="non-albany")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E1,$A$1:$A$5)),$C$1:$C$5)

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, don't forget the `C1:C5` in the last section to have it working for summing up values in column C if they don't equal 1: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("kosher",$A$1:$A$5))*($B$1:$B$5=E1),$C$1:$C$5)+SUMPRODUCT((LOWER($A$1:$A$5)="non-albany")*ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E1,$A$1:$A$5)),$C$1:$C$5)`